# ObjectDisposedException during tests

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

**READ EDIT**

I have a similar implementation to `AsyncCrudAppService` related to filtering queries. When I run tests on top of ABPs implementation of Application Services derived of `AsyncCrudAppServiceBase`, everything runs fine. When I do the same running on top of my custom "filters", I get the following error:

```cs
System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object [...]
Object name: 'DataManagerDbContext'.
```

I know the solution is using `IUnitOfWorkManager` and calling `Begin()` method to define a `UnitOfWork`, but since I am working with AppServices, I thought there was already a `UnitOfWork` defined. These are my methods:

```cs
public PagedResultDto<StateDetails> GetEditorList(EditorRequestDto input)
{
    var query = _stateRepository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.Country).AsQueryable();

    query = ApplySupervisorFilter(query);

    query = query.ApplyFiltering(input, "Name");

    var totalCount = query.Count();

    query = query.ApplySorting<State, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto>(input);

    query = query.ApplyPaging<State, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto>(input);

    var entities = query.ToList();

    return new PagedResultDto<StateDetails>(totalCount, ObjectMapper.Map<List<StateDetails>>(entities));
}

private IQueryable<State> ApplySupervisorFilter(IQueryable<State> query)
{
    if (!SettingManager.GetSettingValue<bool>(AppSettingNames.SupervisorFlag))
    {
        query = ApplyUncategorizedFilter(query);
    }

    return query;
}

private IQueryable<State> ApplyUncategorizedFilter(IQueryable<State> query)
{
    return query.Where(
        p => !p.CountryId.HasValue);
}
```

My passing test (with manual `UnitOfWork`):

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetEditorListWithouSupervisorFlag_Test()
{
    using (UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        await ChangeSupervisorFlag(false);

        var result = _stateAppService.GetEditorList(
            new EditorRequestDto
            {
                MaxResultCount = 10,

            });

        result.Items.Any(p => p.Country == null).ShouldBe(true);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know an solution to this "issue"? It would be annoying to define a `UnitOfWork` for every test I perform. It also seems like I am doing something wrong

**EDIT**

I have solved the issue. I must use an interface for my Application Service when running tests so it is able to mock it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I must use an interface for my Application Service when running tests so it is able to mock it properly